# SonarQube MsBuild, support for C# 7.0 local functions?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

I have a problem where SonarQube thinks that my local function ending in an assignment of a variable out of the scope of the function is useless assignment.  How do I clear this error or bypass it in SonarQube using C# 7.0 definitions?

How do I resolve this?

Function Definition:

```
    public (bool, int) func(string str)
    {
        int variable = 0;

        // C# 7.0 - Local Functions

        void localFunc()
        {
             variable = 1;   //SonarQube complains that this usless assignment needs to be removed
        }


        return (true, variable);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarC# doesn't support (yet) C# 7 features and so some analysis results in weird output. The only thing you can do for now is to mark the issue as `False Positive` under your SonarQube instance.